# Is there a way to get a string out of HTML?

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I'd like a way to generate a filename for osu! beatmaps which I'm downloading. Ideally I would go through the HTML looking for a certain phrase, `beatmapsets?q=`, and get the word(s) that come after the `q=`.

I've tried using lxml.html, however I have little experience in it, and in the code below, it returns an empty list.

```py
class OsuMaps:
    def generateFileName(self, num1=None):
        if not num1:
            print("Missing required argument: 'num1'")
            return
        dl = requests.get(f"https://bloodcat.com/osu/s/{num1.rstrip()}")

        # ..generate FinalName

        tree = fromstring(dl.content)
        FinalName = tree.xpath(
            "//a[contains(@href='beatmapsets?q=')]"
        )

        return FinalName
osu - OsuMaps()
osu.generateFileName("653534") # ideal outcome - "653534 Panda Eyes - ILY"
```

The ideal result is commented in, however I don't know where to start. All I know is the two keywords [that being the songname, ILY, and artist, Panda Eyes] I need are in the HTML as:

```html
<a class="beatmapset-header__details-text beatmapset-header__details-text--title u-ellipsis-overflow" href="/beatmapsets?q=ILY">ILY</a>
```

and

```html
<a class="beatmapset-header__details-text beatmapset-header__details-text--artist" href="/beatmapsets?q=Panda%20Eyes">Panda Eyes</a>
```

I would also need to be able to re-use this code so that it gets `q=<text>` text every time.

Comment: The url `https://bloodcat.com/osu/s/653534` will prompt to download the file `653534 Panda Eyes - ILY.osz` - it's not html content. `len(dl.text)` --> `9123471` The question is not relevant

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest if it automatically downloads the file with the desired name, is there a way for me to maintain the original filename and avoid the whole `generateFilename()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to requests [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content), `requests.get.content` returns the raw bytes response. 
What you need to parse is `dl.text`.

Also has @RomanPerekhrest points out, the given link refers to a binary file so parsing it with `lxml` wont make sense. However you can use `requests.head()` method to get the file name and extract the data you need.

Try something like below:

```
dl = requests.head(f"https://bloodcat.com/osu/s/{num1.rstrip()}") 
fname = dl.headers["Content-Disposition"].split('filename="')[-1].split('";')[0].replace("%20", " ")

# fname == '653534 Panda Eyes - ILY.osz'
```

Comment: How could I use `requests.head()`? I don't quite understand.

Comment: See edited answer. You just need to improve parsing, mine is a bit dirty.

Comment: I've done:
`dl = requests.head(f"https://bloodcat.com/osu/s/{num1.rstrip()}") `, then
`x = dl.headers.get("Content-Disposition")` and then
`y = x.split("filename=\"")[1].split(".osz\";")[0].replace("%20", " ")`
`return y`

Comment: I would just add a check on the response code/content or on `x` to be sure Content-Disposition header is present, and you should be good to go.

Comment: i would also make sure all other percent-encoding is gone too, haha!

Comment: Yes definitely, have a look at `urllib.parse` method.

Comment: I've ran into an issue with `generateFileName("153")`. I've followed the link https://bloodcat.com/osu/s/153 and the map exists, but `dl.headers.get("Content-Disposition")` is `None`.

Comment: Can you post the content of `dl.headers` ?

Comment: Huh.. I've tried running it again right now and it is working. Weird. Sorry!

Comment: Update: it broke again `{'Content-Length': '237', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Location': 'https://bloodcat.com/osu/s/https:/bloodcat.com/osu/s/153', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Frame-Options': 'deny', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-UA-Compatible':
'IE=edge', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=2592000; preload', 'Content-Security-Policy': 'upgrade-insecure-requests;', 'Date': 'Tue, 23 Jul 2019 08:43:57 GMT'}`

Comment: What you get is definitely an error page, you can see that content-type is "text/html". They probably got issues on server side.

Comment: Don't think so, I printed `dl.url` which is `https://bloodcat.com/osu/s/153`, and the link works for me, anyway.

Comment: Oh I've just noticed that the location is `https://bloodcat.com/osu/s/https:/bloodcat.com/osu/s/153` in your header so there is maybe an url issue.

Comment: How could I fix this? I don't have any ideas

Comment: I don't have Python on my current computer, I'll give it a look tonight.

Comment: I've added in this: `if not dl.headers.get("Content-Disposition"):
            num1 = dl.headers.get("Location")` then
           `num1 = num1.split("/s/https")[1].split("osu/s/")[-1]`, then
           `dl = requests.head(f"https://bloodcat.com/osu/s/{num1.rstrip()}") `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196885/discussion-between-may-d-and-xupaii).